Android Firebase Notification does not navigate to specific fragment when app is closed
I am working on an Android app where users receive Firebase notifications for new messages. When a user taps on the notification, the app should navigate to a specific fragment (MessagesFragment) using the Navigation Component. This works perfectly when the app is open, but if the app is closed, tapping the notification opens the Launcher activity which is SplashActivity without navigating to the intended fragment.
Code for MyFirebaseMessagingService
Below is the code for my FirebaseMessagingService, where I create the notification and specify the destination in NavDeepLinkBuilder:
@SuppressLint("MissingFirebaseInstanceTokenRefresh")
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "default_notification_channel"
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id"
        var NOTIFICATION_ID = 0
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createNotificationChannel()
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            getNotificationWithDataPayload(remoteMessage)
        }
    }

    private fun getNotificationWithDataPayload(message: RemoteMessage) {
        val type = message.data["notificationType"]
        val title = message.data["title"]
        val body = message.data["body"]

        val destinationId = when (type) {
            "chat" -> R.id.messagesFragment
            else -> R.id.mainFragment
        }

        val intentBundles = bundleOf(Constants.INTENT_ID to (message.data["typeId"]?.toInt() ?: 0))
        val pendingIntent = createPendingIntentOrder(intentBundles, destinationId)

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        NOTIFICATION_ID += 1
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    private fun createPendingIntentOrder(arguments: Bundle?, destination: Int): PendingIntent {
        return NavDeepLinkBuilder(applicationContext)
            .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.main_nav_graph)
            .setDestination(destination)
            .setArguments(arguments)
            .createPendingIntent()
    }
}


